# How to separate multiple clauses in a DynamoDB Update Expression

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Per the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html):

> An update expression consists of one or more clauses. Each clause
>   begins with a SET, REMOVE, ADD or DELETE keyword. You can include any
>   of these clauses in an update expression, in any order. However, each
>   action keyword can appear only once.

I'm having trouble getting the syntax right for `SET` and `REMOVE` in one `update_expression`:

```
params = {
           key: {
             'id' => { s: '123'  }
           },
           table_name: 'customers'
           expression_attribute_names: {
             '#ADR' => 'address'
             '#ON' => 'order_num'
           },
           expression_attribute_values: {
             ':a' => { s: '123 Main St' }
           },
           update_expression: 'REMOVE #ON, SET #ADR = :a',
         }
  dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1',       
                                       simple_attributes: false)
  dynamodb.update_item(params)
```

I also tried the following:

```
update_expression: 'SET #ADR = :a, REMOVE #ON' => Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "REMOVE", near: ", REMOVE #ON" (Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::ValidationException)

update_expression: ['SET #ADR = :a', 'REMOVE #ON'] => expected params[:update_expression] to be a String, got value ['SET #ADR = :a', 'REMOVE #ON'] (class: Array) instead. (ArgumentError)
```

Can anyone point me to the right docs?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was making it too complicated.
This is the answer:

```
update_expression: 'SET #ADR = :a REMOVE #ON'
```

No delimiter character needed besides the Clause keyword.

Comment: Hehe no problem, it was driving me nuts too :D

Comment: Note that a comma delimiter is to be used if the same operation is to be repeated. Operator name is not repeated in that case.

Comment: Thank you, the documentation is severely lacking examples.